# Slow boot on Fedora 24, possibly caused by plymouth-quit-wait.service

Tags: linux, fedora, boot

So I've been using Fedora 24 for about two weeks now and the one thing that bothers me is the *really* long time it takes to boot. I've been trying to investigate this via `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame` and it seems there are some startup services that take quite a long time, mostly the `plymouth-quit-wait.service`. Since I'm still very new to Linux, I can't decide whether that service is the actual cause or whether it just has to wait for something else to happen.
Dunno if that's relevant, however I'm using the Workstation edition of Fedora 24 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X220 with an i5-2540M CPU.
I'll append the output of `systemd-analyze`, `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical chain` to this question.
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.546s (kernel) + 4.697s (initrd) + 1min 33.630s (userspace) = 1min 40.874s


systemd-analyze blame
     49.647s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     28.356s dnf-makecache.service
     13.163s systemd-journal-flush.service
     12.147s firewalld.service
     11.119s systemd-udev-settle.service
      9.478s dev-mapper-fedora\x2droot.device
      7.549s libvirtd.service
      5.923s udisks2.service
      5.694s abrtd.service
      5.658s accounts-daemon.service
      5.312s chronyd.service
      4.585s polkit.service
      3.809s lvm2-pvscan@8:2.service
      3.594s unbound-anchor.service
      2.736s ModemManager.service
      2.430s proc-fs-nfsd.mount
      2.367s lvm2-monitor.service
      2.287s cups.service
      2.283s dmraid-activation.service
      2.121s systemd-rfkill.service
      2.053s plymouth-start.service
      2.033s systemd-logind.service
      2.014s gssproxy.service
      1.873s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.830s packagekit.service
      1.803s rtkit-daemon.service
      1.794s NetworkManager.service
      1.792s avahi-daemon.service
      1.700s systemd-udevd.service
      1.678s bluetooth.service
      1.423s fedora-readonly.service
      1.367s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.161s abrt-ccpp.service
      1.095s wpa_supplicant.service
       972ms gdm.service
       798ms systemd-journald.service
       795ms dev-mqueue.mount
       790ms upower.service
       738ms systemd-random-seed.service
       734ms user@42.service
       695ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-bc0eb656\x2d624f\x2d4c3d\x2d90a3\x2d321abc24867b.service
       694ms systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-fedora\x2dhome.service
       684ms auditd.service
       656ms tmp.mount
       621ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       521ms systemd-sysctl.service
       479ms fedora-import-state.service
       438ms rpc-statd-notify.service
       395ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       364ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
       356ms dev-hugepages.mount
       319ms home.mount
       299ms systemd-fsck-root.service
       280ms dracut-shutdown.service
       254ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       232ms boot.mount
       230ms plymouth-read-write.service
       226ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       222ms colord.service
       163ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       149ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       136ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       132ms nfs-config.service
        89ms user@1000.service
        87ms blk-availability.service
        76ms dev-mapper-fedora\x2dswap.swap
        73ms systemd-vconsole-setup.service
        70ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        28ms livesys.service
        15ms livesys-late.service
         9ms var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount

systemd-analyze critical chain
graphical.target @1min 33.616s
└─multi-user.target @1min 33.616s
  └─libvirtd.service @37.051s +7.549s
    └─remote-fs.target @36.969s
      └─remote-fs-pre.target @36.969s
        └─iscsi-shutdown.service @36.965s
          └─network.target @36.933s
           └─wpa_supplicant.service @39.880s +1.095s
            └─dbus.service @21.045s
             └─basic.target @20.963s
              └─sockets.target @20.963s
                └─dbus.socket @20.963s
                  └─sysinit.target @20.911s
                    └─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount @1min 32.526s +5ms
                      └─system.slice
                        └─-.slice
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disable some services with this manual:

> http://harald.hoyer.xyz/2013/11/13/fedora-boot-optimization/

I'd tested it for my Fedora 23 on Asus laptop and it's really faster boot then before.